# Явная специализация шаблона класса и заголовочные файлы

Tags: c++

Есть три файла:

main.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
        A<int> ai;
        ai.print();

        A<double> ad; 
        ad.print();

        A<char> ac;
        ac.print();

        return 0;
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

template<typename Type>
void A<Type>::print()
{
        std::cout << "some" << std::endl;
}

//template<>
//class A<int>
//{
//public:
//      void print()
//      {
//              std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
//      }
//};

template class A<int>;
template class A<double>;
template class A<char>;
```

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

template<typename Type>
class A
{
public:
        void print();
};

#endif
```

Выводит на экран:

```
some
some
some
```

Я хочу сделать явную специлизацию шаблона класса `A`, для этого раскомментирую закоментрованные строки. Результат:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc5Vvv83.o: in function `main':
/home/ivan/first/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `A<int>::print()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Если я скопирую это определени и перемещу в хэдэр, то программа заработает и выдаст то, что надо:

```
int
some
some
```

Но я хотел бы не помещать определение метода `A<int>::print()` в хэдэр, поэтому в `test.h` оставляю:

```
template<>
class A<int>
{
public:
      void print();
};
```

а в `test.cpp` помещаю:

```
template<>
void A<int>::print()
{
        std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}
```

результат:

```
test.cpp:11:6: error: template-id ‘print<>’ for ‘void A<int>::print()’ does not match any template declaration
   11 | void A<int>::print()
      |      ^~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:2:
test.h:15:14: note: candidate is: ‘void A<int>::print()’
   15 |         void print();
      |              ^~~~~
```

Вопросы:
1)Как в данном случае оставить определение класса `A<int>` в `test.h`, а определение метода `A<int>::print()` в `test.cpp` и чтобы программа заработала?
2)Как вообще правильно решать такие ситутуации? Может просто следует оставлять определение в хэдэре и не париться(правда, насколько я знаю, таким образом мы увеличим время компиляции)?

Comment: @AlexGlebe а я думал, что добавление cpp файлов это не очень хорошая практика. Да и этот способо работает только если в test.cpp находится определение и класса и метода, а мне интересно возможно ли их разделить на .cpp и .h

Comment: Вам нужно явное инстанцирование. Причем оно должно быть в заголовочном файле. А для специализации определение можно прямо помещать в файл .cpp. @AlexGlebe Незачем раздавать вредные советы.

Comment: @user7860670 так оно же у меня есть внизу `test.cpp`

Comment: Так а должно быть в заголовочном файле.  А `template<> void A<int>::print()` должно быть просто `void A<int>::print()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Три момента:

1. о том, что шаблон явно инстанцируется, и его определение будет доступно в какой-то единице трансляции, следует объявлять в заголовочном файле. Причем для полной специализации `A<int>` этого делать не надо:

```
extern template class A<double>;
extern template class A<char>;
```

2. определение специализации должно быть в заголовочном файле и видно всем пользователям
3. определение функции полностью специализированного класса в .cpp выглядит вот так

```
void A<int>::print()
{
        std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: действительно, писать `template<>` не надо и тогда всё заработает. И определение метода и определине класса тогда можно будет оставить в .cpp. В связи с этим у меня возник еще один вопрос: почему в самом начале моего вопроса, когда я раскоментировал строки, компилятор выдал ошибку? Почему я не могу определить метод внутри класса ?

Comment: @VanechikSpace Специализация класса должна быть определена в заголовочном файле чтобы ее могли видеть все. А так у вас получилось что в одной единице трансляции используется неспециализированный вариант `A<int>`, а в другой - специализированный.